# Read PHP Script from remote file

Tags: php, remote-access

Okay so what I am trying to do is sell modifications to a 2-D game that I built. But I want to make it where the person can not even think about reselling the code therefore what I want to do is make it so they have a code that connects to my server that reads part of the script. It needs to be able to read the PHP file as in variables within the file. I know how to make it where it reads it as a web page but I'm not sure how to make it actually read the inside PHP script and source code. Does anybody know how I would do this?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

enable URL include wrappers and you can include code from another server.

However, if you really want to isolate your code, create an API and make calls to it from the original server.